# D-Link DIR-300 with OpenWRT - How to access bootloader?

Tags: openwrt

I have D-Link DIR-300 (Rev.A1) flashed with OpenWRT "BARRIER BREAKER" (Bleeding Edge, r41531) firmware. Flashing was done according to guide at http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-300

Unfortunalty - this firmware is unstable. Trying to use commands like opkg, sysupgrade or even wget causes router to reboot. At this point router is unusable, as i require web interface (LuCI) and can't install one.

I assume proper course of action is to flash to another version, perhaps one with LuCI preinstalled. To do that i need to access bootloader, as every attempt to use sysupgrade failed (router rebooted).

**How to access bootloader at that point?**

On original firmware there was a one second time window in which i could enter bootloader by telnet on 192.168.20.81 port 9000, via WAN port. This is no longer possible.

There seems to be 5-second window during boot time when router responds to pings to 192.168.1.1, but i get "connection refused" when trying to telnet it on port 9000 during this period.

At http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Micro_Redboot i found:

> At powercyle press and hold the reset button for 2 sec after the switch led's are lit to enable redboot access. After a few seconds you can access it with Telnet at 192.168.1.1 port 9000 for the time set in "Boot script timeout".

...but this doesn't work. Boot script timeout was set to "5" and it does seem consistent with 5-second ping respone i'm seeing.

I *do* have SSH access to the router. Perhaps there is something I could do there to put bootloader in "virgin boot" mode? Or perhaps i'm misinterpreting instructions quoted above? Any help accessing bootloader or other option to reflash device will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This method](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/D-Link_DIR-600#Alternate_Install_Method_using_Emergency_Room_Web_Interface) should work on the DIR-300 as well.

Comment: "It is important to note, DIR-300 Rev A1 and Rev B1 are completely different hardware, different SoC, different procedure." I have Rev.A1. I did try this out, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay close attention to output of fconfig when making initial flash to check which address is used by this specific image. If you don't have a log, check openwrt install docs for specific hardware, they usually have full output of every command.

http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-300 :

```
DD-WRT>fconfig
Run script at boot: true
```

[...]

```
Local IP address: 192.168.1.10
```

You can reach bootloader by Telnet at 192.168.1.10 port 9000 for five seconds. Use ping in separate terminal to determine when address is available.